# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error when trying to execute this query.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM entry";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
```

Comment: You are using OOP with Procedural programming. Use either or.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `mysql_*` is deprecated so please try this:-

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM entry";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice not to use "mysql_query" as it is deprecated, you should try "mysqli" instead, but if you still want to use mysql and not mysqli then you should not mix both.
You should try with anant kumar singh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
```

use this...